# java crawling lacking info

Tags: java, html, xml, web-crawler

I am currently teaching myself website crawling. I figured that there are two ways to get a html code from a website, one using InputStreamReader, and one using jsoup. I've tried the two, but seems like the two are showing different results.

```
import java.io.IOException;
import org.jsoup.Jsoup;
import org.jsoup.nodes.Document;
import org.jsoup.select.Elements;
import java.net.*;
import java.io.*;

public class crawling {
    public static void main(String args[]) {
        try {
            BufferedReader buf;
            String line;
            URL url = new URL("http://www.example.com");
            buf = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(url.openStream()));

            while(buf.readLine() != null) {
                line = buf.readLine();
                System.out.println(line);
                if(line.contains("background-color:")) {
                    line = line.replace("background-color:", " ");
                    System.out.println("I GOT IT: "+ line);
                }
            }

            buf.close();
            System.out.println("\n\nEnd of Streaming\nUse Jsoup\n\n");
        } catch (IOException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        Document doc;
        try {
            doc = Jsoup.connect("http://www.example.com").get();
            System.out.println(doc);
        } catch (IOException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

If I run the code above, the console shows this:

```
<html>
    <title>Example Domain</title>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1" />
    body {
        margin: 0;
        font-family: "Open Sans", "Helvetica Neue", Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;
}
        width: 600px;
        padding: 50px;
        border-radius: 1em;
    a:link, a:visited {
        text-decoration: none;
    @media (max-width: 700px) {
            background-color: #fff;
I GOT IT:               #fff;
        div {
            margin: 0 auto;
            padding: 1em;
    }
</head>
<body>
    <h1>Example Domain</h1>
    domain in examples without prior coordination or asking for permission.</p>
</div>
</html>


End of Streaming
Use Jsoup


<!doctype html>
<html>
 <head> 
  <title>Example Domain</title> 
  <meta charset="utf-8"> 
  <meta http-equiv="Content-type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8"> 
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1"> 
  <style type="text/css">
   body {
        background-color: #f0f0f2;
        margin: 0;
        padding: 0;
        font-family: "Open Sans", "Helvetica Neue", Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;

    }
    div {
        width: 600px;
        margin: 5em auto;
        padding: 50px;
        background-color: #fff;
        border-radius: 1em;
}
    a:link, a:visited {
        color: #38488f;
        text-decoration: none;
    }
    @media (max-width: 700px) {
        body {
             background-color: #fff;
        }
        div {
            width: auto;
            margin: 0 auto;
            border-radius: 0;
            padding: 1em;
        }
    }
    </style> 
 </head> 
<body> 
 <div> 
  <h1>Example Domain</h1> 
  <p>This domain is established to be used for illustrative examples in documents. You may use this domain in examples without prior coordination or asking for permission.</p> 
  <p><a href="http://www.iana.org/domains/example">More information...</a></p> 
  </div>   
 </body>
</html>
```

According to this, it seems like some information are lacking when using the InputStreamReader...why is this kind of error occurring?
For me, it seems a lot easier to using the StreamReader rather than jsoup. But since it seems like it is lacking some info, I feel like I have no choice but to use jsoup.

So I want to know:
1. why using the input stream is lacking some info, and how to fix it.
2. If it is recommended to use jsoup, how can I do the same thing as I did using the input stream, getting a specific string. I've googled it, but I am having a problem in understanding what to do after connecting the url.

Thank you very much in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're skipping alternate lines by calling `buf.readLine()` twice in your loop.

Replace this:

```
while(buf.readLine() != null) {
    line = buf.readLine();
    [...]
```

With this:

```
while((line = buf.readLine()) != null) {
    [...]
```

For #2, JSoup isn't really the way to do that and there are a lot of other cases which you need to handle. But if you still want to do it, there is this hacky way:

```
Elements elems = doc.getElementsByTag("style"); //Select "style" element
for (Element elem : elems) {
    Node child = elem.childNode(0);
    String styleText = child.attr("data").replaceAll("background-color:\\s*#[a-f0-9]+;", ""); //Remove background color attribute
    child.attr("data", styleText); //Set the updated style back into the element
}
System.out.println(doc);
```